# facing Issue in Sequelize ORM

Tags: reactjs

Issue-

We are accessing sequelize from controller directory xyxcontroller.js

Trying to hit ..
`.findOne`
`.findAll`
`.create`
`.build`

But working

The same thing called from

`/models/index.js`
Everything is working

All are written under async & wait.

Comment: You ask about sequelize ORM, and use reactjs tag? that's not the right how to ask a question.

Comment: Please add code, it will help you to reach your answer sooner